# How to call Apex REST API from Javascript?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have two different developer orgs. One contains apex REST web service, and I want to call that REST service from my second org. I have tried to call that REST service using normal ajax post request and forcetk.js, But I got following error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/CustomSettings. Origin
>   https://c.ap1.visual.force.com is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I searched about this problem then I got to know that Salesforce never allows CORS (Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing).

Initially I was using apex to call that REST web service, that time I was able to post data from apex. But as we have callout limitation in salesforce, I want to use javascript.

Can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem. I'm pasting my code here for reference

```
    var result = sforce.connection.login("myname@mymail.com", "mypassword+mysecurityToken");
    sforce.connection.init('{!sessionId}', 'REST web service url'); // here pass current session id of the org from which you are making request.

    sforce.connection.remoteFunction({
           url : REST web service url,
           requestHeaders: {"Authorization":"Bearer "+result.sessionId, "Content-Type":"application/json"}, // here pass the session id of the org in which you have your REST service
           requestData: data to post in JSON format,
           method: "POST",
           onSuccess : function(response) {
                  console.log(response);
              },
           onFailure : function(response) {
                  alert("Failed" + response)
              }
       });
```

Comment: I Have followed the same way u have done. If there is no request data means what we have to give for "requestData" key?

Comment: Hi Dinesh, Sorry for replying you late. If you don't have any data to post, just remove requestData field from code or put empty string as a data to it.

Comment: Hi,With the help of your post and little help over stackexchange i did the service call successfully.

Comment: @TusharKumawat sforce is an object of which class?

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use [ForceTK](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-JavaScript-REST-Toolkit)

Comment: I tried using ForceTK but getting same error as I mentioned in my question. (I've mentioned about ForceTK in my question.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [sforce.connection.remoteFunction](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/Content/sforce_api_ajax_queryresultiterator.htm) funciton from the ajax tookit to get the data from external servers. You will not get the cross-orign policy error.

Comment: Yes, I did try **sforce.connection.remoteFunction**, but it is returning me '401 Unauthorized' error.

Comment: Have you added the domain ( https://ap1.salesforce.com/) in the Remote site setting??

Comment: Yes, I have added [https://ap1.salesforce.com/](https://ap1.salesforce.com/) in my Remote site setting.

Comment: Are you setting either a session id or oAuth token in the header to authenticate access to the other org?

Comment: @AndrewFawcett : Yes Andrew, I'm adding session Id in header. Initially I'm logging in to different org using **sforce.connection.login**. And after getting session Id from login result, I'm passing that session Id in header for authentication.

Comment: @Tushar: Did you get the solution for this? Even I tried with both sforce.connection.remoteFunction and jquery's ajax(). But I ended up getting the same 401 unauthorized exception. But I could make REST API calls from an apex calls..

Comment: @Sameer: No Sameer, I'm also trying various ways to make REST api call. As soon as I get, I will definitely post solution here.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this but could you create a sites website and add your webservice class to that then use the full url to connect to the webservice?

You'd need to put in some sort of authentication/security as the url is public but you should be able to come up with a simple password/token implementation.

Comment: YOu can find more info about this method here http://www.wadewegner.com/2013/03/creating-anonymous-rest-apis-with-salesforce-com/

Comment: I think this solution also not work for me, as salesforce is denying cross-domain requests. And if I create any website for hosting web service then also I need to use different url other than salesforce url. But I'll surely try this solution out.

Answer (score 0):

You can get around this by adding a CORS whitelist entry (`setup -> Security Controls -> CORS`) for the `https://[YOUR_SF_ORG].visual.force.com` host.

For example, in the case of the Question author, you would just need to whitelist `https://c.ap1.visual.force.com`.

I don't *think* this opens any real security holes, but I can't say for sure (XSS might be possible from other ORGs on the same pod?).  It's probably safer to use when the ORG has `My Domain` setup.