# android hybrid app access-control-allow-origin error

Tags: mobile, mobilesdk, android, hybrid, hybrid-remote

I'm getting the following error when running my hyrbrid-remote app in the Android Emulator. Everything works fine in iOS. All of my resources are static resources in SF.

```
07-24 09:53:51.017: I/chromium(4474): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://cs10.salesforce.com/!gap_exec?1406210030920. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Origin 'https://c.cs10.visual.force.com' is therefore not allowed access.",
source: https://c.cs10.visual.force.com/apex/MobileLanding (0)
```

Any suggestions?

Also, if its helpful I'm using SmartStore as well.

EDIT:

I found this in /Smartstore/res/xml/config.xml could this be part of the issue?

```
 <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->
 <access origin="https://force.com" subdomains="true" />
 <access origin="https://salesforce.com" subdomains="true" />
```

EDIT 2:

I found this line inside the `cordova.js` file which I believe is the static resource that causes the error.  This `gap_exec` is what the the error is complaining about.

```
        execXhr.open('HEAD', "/!gap_exec?" + (+new Date()), true);
        if (!vcHeaderValue) {
            vcHeaderValue = /.*\((.*)\)/.exec(navigator.userAgent)[1];
        }
        execXhr.setRequestHeader('vc', vcHeaderValue);
        execXhr.setRequestHeader('rc', ++requestCount);
        if (shouldBundleCommandJson()) {
            execXhr.setRequestHeader('cmds', iOSExec.nativeFetchMessages());
        }
        execXhr.send(null);
```

Comment: can you add the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`?   A similar question in StackOverflow:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008944/how-to-add-an-access-control-allow-origin-header

Comment: @amatorVitae I don't have any access to the salesforce servers

Comment: Good luck and god speed

Answer (score 4):

I've seen this earlier. This can happen on emulator when your hybrid app is invoking Visualforce pages and the root cause is same as when you'd see this issue in a web application. [This](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13607/how-to-call-apex-rest-api-from-javascript) thread explains the issue and the solution.

In most cases, the culprit would be the `requestData` parameter. If you do not need it, remove it. Also, you can use add a remote site setting and then use sforce.connection.remoteFunction to overcome this issue.

This issue will/ should NOT happen on a real device though and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to the server not register these headers.

But for android you can make as patch for api 16 and greater... Find the following code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){ 
  webview.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
}
```

Hope it will work for you.