# Calling @ApexRest web service (services/apexrest) from Visualforce page in same org

Tags: apex, visualforce, apexrest, cors

I've been looking all over the place to figure out how to approach this.  I'm trying to call a web service (services/apexrest) from the same org.  I'm recieving the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://cs45.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/RimsSalesforceConnectRemote. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'https://c.cs45.visual.force.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

I noticed that the origin is different than the target.

- Is there no way to call this web service via JavaScript?
- Is this simply unsupported functionality?

I am able to make successful calls via workbench.developerforce.com so I'm a bit confused.  I do not want this API to be publicly accessible, so I opted to not associated with a Site.

What is also interesting is that the error alludes to a CORS issue, but the 401 code according to Salesforce has more to do with a bad token.

**Update 1***
As suggested, I leveraged the sforce.connect.remoteFunction with a promise to call the Apex rest web service.  Unfortunately due to the requirements, I'm now bumping into a callout depth threshold:

`[{"errorCode":"APEX_ERROR","message":"System.CalloutException: Callout loop not allowed\n\nClass.RimsSalesforceConnectRemote.sendRequest: line 19, column 1\nClass.RimsSalesforceConnectRemote.doPost: line 33, column 1"}]`

To clarify my architecture is as follows:
`Client -> Apex Rest web service -> 3rd Party API`

So far I've tried to make direct calls to the Apex Rest web service via the `$http` AngularJS module and now via the `sforce.connection.remoteFunction`.

I definitely didn't think that simply calling the Apex Rest web service would be such a pain.  Testing via developer workbench was so simply.  Hair is falling out.

Comment: You should be able to use the answer already posted here: [How to call Apex REST API from Javascript?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13607/how-to-call-apex-rest-api-from-javascript)